# Change CSS depending on whether a checkbox that is stored in local storage is active/checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I would like to be able to check if a checkbox has been checked against a value in local storage. If it is checked I would like to apply a background colour to a part of the page.

[Page to apply CSS http://upskillapps.com/resources/1.png](http://upskillapps.com/resources/1.png)

My local storage data looks like the following:

[Local storage data http://upskillapps.com/resources/2.png](http://upskillapps.com/resources/2.png)

If the completion checkbox is active I would like to apply a green background and if not an orange background.

I have the following code so far but am new to JS and so it needs a lot of work:

```
function highlightComplete() {
  if (DevPlan.completion == 'true') {
    info-row.addClass('background-green');
  } else if (DevPlan.completion == 'false') {
    info-row.addClass('background-orange');
  } 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What problems are you having with the code you wrote?  Is it not functioning as you expect it to, or is it throwing some kind of error?  I'm unsure if you want us to help you or write it for you.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your reply. I have had a stab at the code myself but it is not working, the CSS is not being applied. If someone could provide example coding that would be extremely useful then I can potentially put a Fiddle together and go from there.

Comment: @Mark-Bigrock, is the CSS not being applied, or is the CSS _class_ not being added to the element?

Comment: @apoco it seems as though it may not getting added to the element in the first instance and thus not applied.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //this function executes on page load
    if (!localStorage.getItem('color')) { //if our value does not already exist, we'll default it to green
        localStorage.setItem('color', 'green');
        $('#div').addClass('green');
    } else { //our value exists already
        if (localStorage.getItem('color') == 'green') {
            $('#div').addClass('green');
        } else {
            $('#div').addClass('red');
        }
    }
});

$('button').click(function () {
    var color = localStorage.getItem('color');
    if (color == 'green') {
        $('#div').removeClass().addClass('red');
        color = 'red';
    } else {
        $('#div').removeClass().addClass('green');
        color = 'green';
    }
    localStorage.setItem('color', color);
});
```

Basically, the idea here is to check for the value on page load and set your CSS based on that, then wait for user input to change the value and CSS together.

Here's what this code looks like in action: http://output.jsbin.com/yexahatoye

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks very much for this. I would only want the colour to be applied on page load so the button click function wouldnt be required. How do I adjust your code to pick a specific item/key in local storage and then apply the CSS to a specific class on the page?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for, but it should not be hard to do yourself.  My example demonstrates how to get and set values in local storage, and how to add and remove classes using jQuery.  Is there anything else you are confused about?

Comment: I have not explained myself properly, the checkbox you see in the images is not the one I am checking to see if it is checked or not. It is a checkobox that marks the development plan as completed per say, so it is in the completion table in local storage. I tried to adjust your code by doing the following - http://jsbin.com/jugefewuve/edit?html,css,js,output . But I am not getting the desired result. Apologies for any confusion or frustration caused.

Comment: I don't see a checkbox anywhere on that JSBin.  Are you saying that you want a checkbox that, when checked, will apply a CSS class to a particular element and save it in localStorage so that on the next page load, that CSS class is still applied to said element?

Comment: Yes you are right there is not a checkbox on that page, it is on the previous page where a form is filled in. Once the form is filled in and the save button selected the checkbox is saved as either active or not (true or false). The user is then redirected to the history page which lists the past forms that have been filled in. On page load I would like to check if this checkbox is active or not and then apply a background colour to each row on the history page so a user can see what is completed and what is not. The checkbox is stored in the object=devPlan and table=completion.

Comment: In that case, the code inside of the `$(document).ready` function is what you are looking for.  On page load, you need to get the value contained inside of local storage.  Depending in its value, you can then set a CSS class to a particular div, just like I did in mine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done just that. Please could you tell me how I write the select code for picking something that is in a table within an object stored within local storage i.e. object=devPlan and table=completion. I have tried with no luck to date. You can see the structure in my second image in the original question. Thank you for your help so far it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since Objects in Javascript are really just containers with key-value pairs, you would just access your information by its key.  If the object in local storage is called `tables`, and you want to get its child array, `completion`, and from that, you want to get the 0th element, you do something like `localStorage.getItem('tables').completion[0]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am now logging what i need in the console - var devPlan = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("devPlan"));
console.log (devPlan[0].tables.completion[0].active); . 
When I try and get the items by putting localStorage.getItem('devPlan[0]').tables.completion[0].active   
I get an undefined error. I cant seem to find the issue with the statement.  

I have realised I need to loop through each item checking all the data in local storage within the devPlan object i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.. What would be the best way of achieving this? 
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('devPlan[0]')` means that its getting the item stored with the key of "devPlan[0]".  Your object was stored with key "devPlan", so you'd need to do `localStorage.getItem('devPlan')`.  Then, if you want to get the 0th element, you'd reference it using `[0]`.  So it would look like this: `localStorage.getItem('devPlan')[0]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

If I wanted to get all the items that sit within the object devplan (rows 0, 1, 2 etc.) specifically looking for the value against the completion item i.e. a loop through each row how would that be accomplished. 

It would look like this for the 0th item ('devPlan')[0].tables.completion[0].active BUT I would like to check ('devPlan')[0,1,2,3,4,5 etc.).tables.completion.active - I will be checking to see if each item has a value against active == 'true' i.e. active checkbox and apply CSS accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

I have tried what you have suggested: 

for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var item = localStorage.getItem('devPlan')[i].tables.completion[0].active;
    //do something with item
 if (item=="true") {
  $('#background').addClass('background-green');
  } else {
  $('#background').addClass('background-amber');
  }
 }
It gives an undefined error for .tables , TypeError: localStorage.getItem(...)[i].tables is undefined

Comment: http://pastie.org/10328067

This will log the correct item: var devPlan = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("devPlan"));
console.log (devPlan[0].tables.completion[0].active); 

BUT if I try and add the i variable I get the undefined error.

Comment: Yeah, I was just guessing how many of them there were based on one of your comments, but its entirely possible that there aren't 5 elements in your devPlan variable, so when trying to access the ones that don't exist, you get an error.  You can use `.length` to see how many items are in an array so you don't accidentally try to access one that doesn't exist.  So it would look something like this: http://pastie.org/10328119

Comment: Thanks for your reply as always. Unfortunately I have tried to run that code in the console and it is still coming up with an undefined error - TypeError: devPlan[i].tables is undefined. It is strange as we are stating that the variable i will be less than the length of the devPlan object which should always be the case. 
Do you have any suggestions as to what the issue may be?
Thanks Mark

Comment: I changed the code to this to get the devPlan string: var devPlan = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("devPlan"));
for (var i = 0; i < devPlan.length; i++) {
    var item = devPlan[i].tables.completion[0].active;
    if (item=="true") {
       $('#background').addClass('background-green');
    } else {
       $('#background').addClass('background-amber');
    }
} 

It runs ok but applies Amber whether the checkbox is checked or not i.e. true and false

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intended, but you are checking to see if the string contained in `devPlan[i].tables.completion[0].active` is "true" instead of checking against the boolean value `true`.  Is `devPlan[i].tables.completion[0].active` supposed to be a string or a boolean?

Comment: It is stored in local storage as "true" or "false" which is a string OR am I wrong? In effect the check is to see whether the field is either "true" or "false".

Someone else suggested that I use the following:

if ("input:ischecked") { 
$('#background').addClass('background-green'); } 
else { 
$('#background').addClass('background-amber'); } 
}

But then I get green being applied regardless of whether the value is true or false.

Comment: That's because "input:ischecked" is just a string, and when it is the only parameter of an if expression, it will always evaluate to a truthy value.  You could replace "input:ischecked" with "thisIsARandomString" and it would still be true.

Comment: Sorry Michael, that was my fault for putting it in "" and I can see why it is an issue. 

I am able to log the values to the console with:

var devPlan = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("devPlan"));
for (var i = 0; i < devPlan.length; i++) {
    var item = devPlan[i].tables.completion[0].active;
  console.log (item);}

Comment: But when I add the action to the statement it always results in green: 
for (var i = 0; i < devPlan.length; i++) {
    var item = devPlan[i].tables.completion[0].active;
    if (item=="true") {
       $('#background').addClass('background-green');
   } else { if (item!="true") {
       $('#background').addClass('background-amber');
     }
    }
   }
I have added an else condition, could you tell me what is wrong it seems very close.

Comment: My understanding of this expression: for (var i = 0; i < devPlan.length; i++) { var item = devPlan[i].tables.completion[0].active;
if (item=="true") {
 $('#background').addClass('background-green'); }
else {
 $('#background').addClass('background-amber'); }
}
Is it will loop through the completion[0] items checking whether their value equals "true", if it does green is applied and if not then amber is applied. Am I missing something?

Comment: That statement is correct, but there's a couple of reasons why it isn't behaving the way you expect it to.  First, remember that a DOM element can have more than one class.  So let's say that your for loop runs twice, and your if statement returns true the first time, and false the second time.  In this case, your #background element will have both of these classes, and you will see whichever style has the higher precedence in your stylesheet, and the other one will be overridden.  If you want to keep using your for loop, you will have to first remove the other class, then add the new one.

Comment: Second, I am not sure why you are using a for loop in the first place.  Even if you first removed all classes from #background before adding a new one, the only iteration of the for loop that matters would be the last one.  Every change made by a previous iteration will be overridden in the following one.

Comment: I have noticed another issue, the #background is the same ID for all of the rows which causes an issue too. I need to dynamically assign the CSS to background_ITEM_ID as opposed to just background. Would you be able to suggest how I would write the CSS ID which is currently "#background" to include the row ID?

If I did that using the for loop, it would be targetting a different ID and applying the CSS uniquely. This should then work or am I wrong again?

Comment: IDs are intended to be unique throughout the document.  (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) So that's another issue entirely.  I'd assign a class for every row and a unique ID for each row, perhaps one that contains a number that you can use in a for loop.  That way, your jQuery selector could be something like `$('.className#uniqueID1')`, with each subsequent row increasing the number at the end by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Michael Parker for your help.

I now have a solution after fiddling about for a while and learning a lot in the process:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < devPlan.length; i++) {
            var item = devPlan[i].tables.completion[0].active;
            if (item == true) {
                $('#' + i).find('.info-row').addClass('background-green');
            }
            else {
                $('#' + i).find('.info-row').addClass('background-amber');
            }
        }
```

To apply the CSS I have used the table row ID to apply the CSS. Hopefully it helps someone else.